# Select list entries based on Numpy Array Values (Same Index)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, selection

My approach works, but it somehow looks clumsy. I was wondering if there is a better way of doing things.

I have a simple List with data-tuples (`baseDataList`), a function that processes that list (`calculate_results`) to generate a numpy.ndarray with results (`resultData`). The length and index of `baseDataList` and Numpy `resultData` match. Now I want to go back and select all entries of `baseDataList` based on the results of `resultData`. If an `resultData` entry is <0, it is excluded, otherwise entries of `baseDataList` are grouped based on the distinct values in `resultData`.

Below I solved this by creating a new list, adding empty values and looping through `resultData`. This is not only clumsy, I think it also creates an overhead of data since I have now 3 variables: `baseDataList`, `resultData` and `resultList` - where I really only need a grouped version of `baseDataList`. Any ideas on how to improve this?

```py
    resultData, baseDataList = calculate_results(selection_value)         
    number_of_validResults = len(np.unique(resultData>=0))
    idx = 0
    resultList = [[] for x in range(number_of_validResults)] 
    for x in resultData:
        if x >= 0: # no resultData: x = -1
            resultList[x].append(baseDataList[idx])
        idx+=1
```

This is example output for the three elements:

```py
print(str(type(baseDataList)))
print("baseDataList: ")
for s in baseDataList[:2]:
    print(*s

#<class 'list'>
#baseDataList:
#43.646556 -79.470988 5761688733 ...
#43.645314 -79.462791 5761688679 ...

print(str(type(resultData)))
print("resultData: ")
print(str(type(resultData)))
print("Unique: " + str(len(np.unique(resultData>=0)))

#<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
#resultData:
#[ 0 -1  0  5  5 -1  4 10 10  5 10 10 10 10 -1 10 10 10 10 10  4  4  6  1  2
#5  9 -1 10 10 10  6 10  8 10 10  6  8 10 10  3  9 10 10 10  6  6  4  6  6
#10  5  5  4  6 10  6  5 10  5 10 10 10  6 -1  6  4  4 10 10 10 10 10 10  7
#4 10 -1 -1 10  9 -1  5  3  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  4  6  6  4  6  6  6  6  6
#6  6  6  6  6  8 -1  6 10 10  4  4 10  9 -1  9 10 10  5  9 10  4  5  5 10
#6 10 10  5 10  6  5  6 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10  6  4  5 10 -1  9  9  9
#6 10 10  6  1  6 10 10 10 10 10 10  6  5  9 10 10  6 10 10 10 -1  4  3  9
#9  7  5 10 10 10  4  8 -1 -1  6  4  4  6 10  9  6 10  9 10  1  6 10 10 10
#10 -1  6 10 10  9 10 10  2 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
#10 10 10 10 10 -1  1 10 10  1  1 10 10  1 -1 10  1 10 10 10 10 10 10  9 10
#11 11 -1  6  1  6 -1 10  6  4  8 10 10 10 10  8 10 10 10 10 10 11  6 12 12
#10  4 10 10  6  4 -1  4 -1  4  4  4  4  4  4  4 -1  4]
#Unique: 13

print("resultList: ")
print(str(type(resultList)))
for s in resultList[:2]:
    print(*s)
#<class 'list'>    
#resultList:
#namedResult_tuple(lat=43.646556, lng=79.470988, guid='5761688733', ...)
#namedResult_tuple(lat=43.645314, lng=-79.462791, guid='5761688679', ...)
#...
```

Comment: Questions usually benefit from sample input and expected output.

Comment: Thank you, I have added sample output for my three elements! -1 means: noise points. I want to exclude these. Every number > 0 refers to a cluster of points detected by a clustering function (e.g. every point that is assigned to "5" means: "these points belong to cluster number 5")